# utf-32 advantage explanation

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, utf-32

in the online [diveintopython3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html#one-ring-to-rule-them-all) book,it says that the advantage of utf-32 and utf-16 is that

> UTF-32 is a straightforward encoding; it takes each Unicode character
>   (a 4-byte number) and represents the character with that same number.
>   This has some advantages, the most important being that you can find
>   the Nth character of a string in constant time, because the Nth
>   character starts at the 4×Nth byte

can somebody explain this? if possible with an example..I am not sure I have quite understood it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual encoding of Unicode is UTF-8; UTF-8 represents characters with a variable number of bytes.  For instance, the “L” character is encoded with a single byte (0x4c) while the “é” is encoded with two bytes (0xc3, 0xa9).  So in a UTF-8 encoding, the word “Lézard” takes 7 bytes, and you cannot get the Nth character without decoding all characters before (you don't know how many bytes each character needs).

In UTF-32, *all* characters use 4 bytes, so to get the Nth character, you only need to go to byte 4×(N-1).  First character is at position 0, second at position 4, third at position 8, etc.

Comment: The problem is though that 'character' (as in 'code point') has very little meaning in Unicode. You can see 'how twitter counts characters' or, http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 0):

As Pavel said, character has little meaning, and their closest equivalents mean different things in different languages (See: Indic Script). Even though it is so, it is far easy to count whatever you think a character is, despite different meanings, in UTF-32. Be it a Latin 'A', Chandrakala, கா, etc. because of fixed width.